# SQL Stock multiple information in a field or create tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having conception difficulties to implement something in a database. I have two solutions for a problem, and I was wondering which one is the best.

Problem :

Let's picture a table speciality with 2 fields : speciality_id and speciality_name. 
So for example :

```
1 - Mage
2 - Warrior
3 - Priest
```

Now, I have a table user with fields such as user_id, name, firstname etc ...
In this table, there is a field called speciality. The speciality stores an integer, corresponding to the speciality_id of the table speciality.

That would be acceptable for users that have only one speciality. I want to improve the model to be able to have multiple specialities for a user.

Here are my two solutions :

Create a table 'solution1' which link the user_id with the speciality_id and remove the speciality field in the user table. So for a user which has 2 specialities, 2 rows will be created in the table 'solution1'.

Change the type of the field speciality in the user table to be able to write down the specialities, separated with commas.
For example 2;3

The problem I got with the second solution is for making foreign keys between my table user and my table specialities, to link them. I may have a bit more difficulties with the PHP in the future too, while wanting to get the specilities for a user (will need to use a parser I guess).

Which solution do you find is the best ?

Thanks.

Comment: Solution 1 is the way to go IMHO, because it lets you keep a tidy and normalized database.  Solution 2 is bad because it requires storing CSV which is hard to deal with when querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely go with your first solution.

Create a third "Many-to-Many" table that allows you to relate a user to multiple specialties. This is the only way to go in your case.

When designing tables, you always want to have each column contain one and only one data element. Think about what querying your second solution would look like. What would you do when you wanted to see all users who had a given specialty?

You might try something like this:

```
select * from user where specialty like '%2%'
```

Well, what happens when you have specialties that go to 12? Now "2" matches multiple entities. You could devolve further and try to be tricky, but...you really should just make your data design as normal as possible to avoid all the mess, headache, and errors. Go with Solution 1.

Answer (score 1):

i think the best way is to follow solution1 cause solution2 will end up will lot of  complexity later on